# Floating Div Falling

Tags: html, css

This is a simple piece of code, but the solutions I've tried for this problem haven't been working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        #ONE {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #TWO {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>

    <div id="ONE"></div>
    <div id="TWO"></div>

</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Upon resizing the browser, the "**TWO**" `div` falls below "**ONE**". I want to be able to keep the divs horizontal. Without resizing them based on screen width, I haven't found a suitable way to keep them horizontal on one line.

https://jsfiddle.net/hra5t6v0/

Comment: Do the two `div` elements need to keep their width (500px x 2), regardless of the window size?

Comment: So what in your opinion should happen when viewport width becomes smaller than 1004px?

Comment: Has your question not been answered yet?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @connexo for more modern broswers that support `flexbox`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  display: flex;
}
#ONE,
#TWO {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
}
#ONE {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#TWO {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="ONE"></div>
  <div id="TWO"></div>
</header>
```

Again, this forces a scrollbar  due to overflow at widths less than 1004px (or 1000px if using `box-sizing:border-box`).

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hra5t6v0/4/)

A couple of advantages.

Firstly, the default for `flexbox` is nowrap so you don't have to explicitly state it.

Secondly, it doesn't suffer from the `white-space` issue requiring a the font reset that is often employed.

**Note:** In fact, you could use *both* techniques and the `flexbox` will override the `inline-block` if the broswer supports it....progresive enhancment!

[**JSfiddle Demo (both)**](https://jsfiddle.net/hra5t6v0/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/1j7xter3/10/

```
header{width: 1000px;}        

#ONE {
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
}
#TWO {
            float: left;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: why not using instead of calc(100%/2), 50% :/ ?

Comment: @Devian same thing, patato potato

Comment: @Devian I always use `calc()` just for when I want to use thick borders and such, but I always find myself using `calc()` when it is not really needed.

Comment: Sorry brah, I didnt see the second part of your post , :P

Comment: @nersoh are we really going to have this discussion here?! There are 1,000 ways to skin a cat! pick one, if it works, use it, I don't care!

Comment: I don't recommend using calc(), it's unneccessary in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a combination of `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;`.

This way you can stick to your fixed widths and the two `div` will stay in one line (which of course causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear if the viewport width becomes smaller than 1004px).

```
header {
    font-size: 0; /* solves unwanted space between #ONE and #TWO */
    white-space: nowrap; /* this makes inline-block children not wrap */
}
#ONE, #TWO {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px; /* reset font-size on children to whatever you need */
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}
#ONE {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#TWO {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hra5t6v0/3/